# How to read http_request date, sent by browser?

Tags: php, http, httprequest

I need to know what time exactly the http request from the browser was sent to my PHP program on the server. I am trying to do this because my program requires a time-based sync between the server and the clients.

What I have seen in my research is the `getallheaders()` function which will return all http-request headers, but there was never a date/time inside. My code looks

```
<?php

foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
    echo "$name: $value\n";
}
```

and the result looks like:

```
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

As you see, there is no `date` in the header. How can I retrieve the `date` of http request using PHP?

Comment: Everything is in `$_SERVER`

Answer (score 0):

Try it :)

```
<?php

$timestamp = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']; 
$TimeRequest = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s", $timestamp); // convert Unix time :)

echo "Request sent at time : ".$TimeRequest;
?>
```

Comment: but doesn't `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];` refer to the time when the request was     received     by the server? In fact, I need the time when it was SENT.

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP `$_SERVER` [doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

> 'REQUEST_TIME'
>       The timestamp of the start of the request. Available since PHP 5.1.0.
>
> 'REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT'
>       The timestamp of the start of the request, with microsecond precision. Available since PHP 5.4.0.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but `$_SERVER` refers to the time of the server, not the browser. I need to see what time the request was sent by the browser, not its receiving by the server.